# Draw rectangle with only knowing two points

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to write a program which draws a rectangle around two points. Going off of the [Google Maps example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-complex), I want to draw a rectangle around Penn Station (40.7506, 73.9939) and City Hall (40.7127, 74.0059). Essentially, I am wanting to mimick this cropped image of the two places:

[image]

The borders of this image would be the rectangle. The part I'm having trouble is building one when I only know the two points as I mentioned above. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to set the viewport to the smallest area around those two points?

Comment: Also, you probably want to include the path to get there in the image as well, right?  Otherwise, you'll have scenarios where the path might possible go outside the rectangle that fits the 2 points.  Also, are you trying to capture a screenshot, emulate this in canvas?  Give us some more info on what you're trying to implement.

Comment: Around the 2 points or around the directions path?

Comment: How are you generating the map?  Are you using the [Google Maps Javascript API v3 DirectionsService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions)?  If so, what does the code to do that look like?

Answer (score 0):

To draw a rectangle around Penn Station (40.7506, 73.9939) and City Hall (40.7127, 74.0059), add those two coordinates to an empty bounds object, then use that as the `bounds` option for the [google.maps.Rectangle](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Rectangle)

```
// Penn Station (40.7506, 73.9939) 
// City Hall (40.7127, 74.0059)
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var pennStation = new google.maps.LatLng(40.7506, -73.9939);
bounds.extend(pennStation);
var cityHall = new google.maps.LatLng(40.7127, -74.0059);
bounds.extend(cityHall);
var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
  map: map,
  bounds: bounds
});
```

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  // Penn Station (40.7506, 73.9939) 
  // City Hall (40.7127, 74.0059)
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var pennStation = new google.maps.LatLng(40.7506, -73.9939);
  bounds.extend(pennStation);
  var cityHall = new google.maps.LatLng(40.7127, -74.0059);
  bounds.extend(cityHall);
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    map: map,
    bounds: bounds
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```